Gmsh - Flow in a Channel with Obstacle
I need some help with this mesh. I want to make sure that the internal part of the circle is not filled by the triangles of the mesh. How can I modify the code below to achieve this?
Mesh.MshFileVersion = 2.2;
// Definir o tamanho da malha
lc = 0.25;
// Definir os pontos do retângulo
Point(1) = {0, 0, 0, lc};
Point(2) = {8, 0, 0, lc};
Point(3) = {8, 2, 0, lc};
Point(4) = {0, 2, 0, lc};
// Definir os pontos do círculo (obstáculo)
xc = 4; // Coordenada x do centro do círculo
yc = 1; // Coordenada y do centro do círculo
r = 0.2; // Raio do círculo
// Definir pontos ao redor do círculo
Point(5) = {xc, yc + r, 0, lc}; // Ponto superior
Point(6) = {xc, yc, 0, lc}; // Ponto central
Point(7) = {xc, yc -r, 0, lc}; // Ponto inferior
// Definir as linhas do retângulo
Line(1) = {1, 2};
Line(2) = {2, 3};
Line(3) = {3, 4};
Line(4) = {4, 1};
// Definir o círculo (completo)
Circle(5) = {7, 6, 5}; // Primeiro metade do círculo
Circle(6) = {5, 6, 7}; // Segundo metade  do círculo
// Criar a superfície do retângulo
Curve Loop(1) = {1, 2, 3, 4};
Plane Surface(1) = {1};
// Criar a superfície do círculo
Curve Loop(2) = {5, 6, 7};
Plane Surface(2) = {2};
// Subtrair o círculo do retângulo
BooleanDifference { Surface{1}; Delete; } { Surface{2}; Delete; };
// Configurar a malha
Transfinite Surface {1};

This is a question better asked on the gmsh forums.

Hey Wolfgang, do you know how I can solve this issue? It seems simple, but the subtraction isn’t working. I just need to exclude the internal surface of the circle from the generated mesh.

I have essentially no experience with gmsh. As I say above, ask this question on the gmsh forum. That's where all the people who know this code hang out.
